# LINQ where clause using Generic IQueryable source

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to make a method that will filter through an IQueryable datasource with a generic type. I want to have a search method that I could reuse for each of the tables that I will be creating. Preferably I would like to be able to pass a field type as well into this so that I can narrow the search, but also wouldn't care if it just looked into every field.

So far I have this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(IQueryable<T> dataSource, string searchFor)
{
    foreach(var variable in dataSource) 
    {
        dataSource = dataSource.Where(var.Contains(searchFor));
    }
}
```

i don't know if this really possible, but it would save me a ton of coding since I will have to implement a new search method for each new table that I would be viewing.

Comment: Do you want to do a search on one or more columns from the table based on a string name of a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `for` loop here and have mistake in this line:

```
dataSource = dataSource.Where(var.Contains(searchFor));
```

You can define interface in this way:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool Contains(string searchFor);
}
```

and now you can write your function in the following way:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(IQueryable<T> dataSource, string searchFor) where T:IMyInterface
{

    return dataSource.Where(x=>x.Contains(searchFor));
}
```

Comment: Will this just look into all fields then in that datasource? And if it does, is there a way to specify a field that you would like to search in? Maybe just passing it in as a parameter as well?

Comment: @Pinball125 you will need to implement Contains for every Table Class that you want to use with this function. You can specify the field in that Contains method as you wish. LINQ Where is going on the whole collection on which it was called and returning items which pass the statement.

Comment: This will not work for most IQueryable implementations. This is more suitable for an IEnumerable